# Avoiding divide by zero error when summing this year vs last year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a script that shows year over year growth by member.  However we are always adding or dropping members so LY may not exist for some.  The script I tried using is;

```
select
DBA as 'Retailor',
sum(case when TranDate between @start and @end then TranAmount else 0 end)/
sum(case when TranDate between dateadd(year, -1, @start) and dateadd(year, -1, @end) then TranAmount else 0 end) -1
```

However I keep ending up with a divide by zero error.  I have also tried replacing else 0 with nullif(0,0) which I found in a previous answer but still have the same issues.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am a rookie, I have only been using SQL for 3 months by self teaching

Comment: In case the "sum(case when TranDate between dateadd(year, -1, @start) and dateadd(year, -1, @end) then TranAmount else 0 end) -1" is Zero, what would be the result of that division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in your case is to simply remove the `else 0` in the denominator:

```
(sum(case when TranDate between @start and @end then TranAmount else 0 end)/
 sum(case when TranDate between dateadd(year, -1, @start) and dateadd(year, -1, @end)
          then TranAmount 
     end) - 1
```

Assuming that `TranAmount is always greater than 0, this will return`NULL` if there are no matches.

Absent that simple change, the next easiest method is `NULLIF()`:

```
(sum(case when TranDate between @start and @end then TranAmount else 0 end)/
 nullif(sum(case when TranDate between dateadd(year, -1, @start) and dateadd(year, -1, @end)
                 then TranAmount 
            end), 0) - 1
```

Comment: Perfect the nullif around the denominator worked with out issue.  When I removed the else 0 it returned the following message; Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mesa Don't just thank him. G. Accept his answer. Otherwise, you are being kind of rude ;)